# Loading an iImage in a custom DialogBox from a URL with Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have created a method where I can load an image from Drawable folder which is working fine but when I was trying load image from **URL** and set it on my custom layout's Imageview, it returns just:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
```

My Java Code is:

```
public void CustomDialogLoadImage() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    ImageView FF_ReceiptImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.FF_ReceiptImage);
    Picasso.with(ConveyanceAmtUpdateApprove.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(FF_ReceiptImage);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogbox_image);
    dialog.show(); 
}
```

My Custom Dialog Box is:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FF_ReceiptImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mobile_sales_img"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I Have tried may way to solved this but it is Resolved Please Help Me...

Comment: try moving your code after dialog.show()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After i check it one more time, i see weird things in 4th line.

Try this

```
public void CustomDialogLoadImage() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogbox_image);
    ImageView FF_ReceiptImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.FF_ReceiptImage);
    Picasso.with(ConveyanceAmtUpdateApprove.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(FF_ReceiptImage);

    dialog.show(); 
}
```

Or you have to do it inside View which is it already inflate first, this is sample code

```
public class ImageDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String ARG_IMAGE_URI = "arg_image_uri";
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE_NAME = "arg_image_name";
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE_ID_CHANNEL = "arg_image_id_channel";

    public ImageDialog(){ // if no argument you can use empty constructor }
    public static ImageDialog getInstance(String uriStr, String imageName, int idChannel){

        ImageDialog imageDialog = new ImageDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_IMAGE_URI, uriStr);
        bundle.putString(ARG_IMAGE_NAME, imageName);
        bundle.putInt(ARG_IMAGE_ID_CHANNEL, idChannel);
        imageDialog.setArguments(bundle);
        return imageDialog;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // inflate first with your own layout dialog 
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_image_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Look this part
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.popup_image);
        //-------------
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            String name = bundle.getString(ARG_IMAGE_NAME);
            getDialog().setTitle(name);
            String imageUri = bundle.getString(ARG_IMAGE_URI);
            int idChannel = bundle.getInt(ARG_IMAGE_ID_CHANNEL);
            if(idChannel == 0){
                Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(new File(imageUri))
                        .into(imageView);

            }else {
                Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(imageUri)
                        .into(imageView);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And to call this dialog perform this action

```
ImageDialog dialog = ImageDialog.getInstance(item.getImageUrl(), item.getName(), 1);
                dialog.show(fragmentManager, null);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nanda Z ... I am really Appropriate that you have Solved it very Quick Session

Comment: I am glad to hear that. This is the place that makes coding world not that scary... i share what i have. Btw, You can upvote my answer so it will be helpful to other developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CustomDialogLoadImage() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogbox_image);
    ImageView FF_ReceiptImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.FF_ReceiptImage); 
    dialog.show();
Picasso.with(ConveyanceAmtUpdateApprove.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(FF_ReceiptImage);
}
```

will work fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to get a view which is null

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialogbox_image,null,false);
ImageView dialogImage= dialogView.findViewById(R.id.FF_ReceiptImage);
Picasso.with(ConveyanceAmtUpdateApprove.this)
.load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
.into(dialogViewImage);
dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
dialog.show();
```